# Why is there a gap in Application Insights dependency Timeline?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

We have an asp.net core api hosted on Azure Websites that does the following:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
var t1 = InsertToTableStorageAsync();
sw.Start(); // Measure the actual time between these two calls
// more code here
sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); //20 ms in debug mode
var r2 = await PerformAnAzureSearchAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
//more code here
var r1 = await t1.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When looking at insights we see the following dependency timeline:
[image]

Note the gap between when the storage dependency ends and when the search dependency starts. That is over 100ms. Is this a bug within Insights portal, reporting? Or is this something we can improve with our code?

*UPDATE 1/30/2018*

I decided to measure the time between the calls with a `Stopwatch` while debugging and the result was `20ms`, five times faster than the reported `~100ms` reported by Insights. I know I was debugging, but I would assume that the release version is even faster.

Answer (score 1):

> The gap between those two calls is huge and it doesn't look right. Is this a bug in Application Insights?

I suppose not. I also test on my side, the result works like you. The status is success(green). It does take a period of time to load the dependencies. And it seems that you call two different dependencies, so you really need to take a period of time to load two dependencies to your project. Just like you run your page in browser, you also need a period of time to view the page. You could read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies)(**Request timeline**), the official  result also  gap a period of time between two calls.

> **Request timeline**
>
> In a different case, there is no dependency call that is particularly long. But by switching to the timeline view, we can see where the delay occurred in our internal processing:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

We are experiencing the same and working to isolate why it is taking so long between the request and the database dependency call...In some cases it could be 30 seconds or more...

[image]

Comment: this should have been a comment, not an aswer